# How do I keep shell or IDLE shell from opening when running wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have tried using pythonw and this only works if I drop and drag the file onto it. I remember reading somewhere there is a way to keep this from happening in the code but I can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To run it with `pythonw.exe` just give your file a `.pyw` extension.

Comment: Or create a shortcut that runs pythonw.exe yourscript.py